# PHP/Python/Bash Emulator

Tags: javascript, php, python, json, ajax

I am having to accomplish a custom terminal using PHP/JS/Python on a LAMP stack server to be able to execute scripts. I am able to: generate the command to be executed, run the script, and return the output. There are scripts that must be run that have a continuous (endless loop) that are to be killed using *kill PID*. However, I need to be able to call the output from the Python script that is running in the background. Example:

```
/*** PHP ***/
  <?php
    // AJAX call return
    $data = (object) array();
    $data->command = $_POST['command'];
    exec('python3 ' . $data->command . ' > /dev/null &', $data->output, $data->err);
    die(json_encore($data));
  ?>

/*** HTML ***/
  <HTML>
    <head>
      function submitForm(){
        //... function submits and returns json_object using AJAX
        var data = JSON.parse(__return__);
        var pre = document.createElement("PRE");
        for(var index = 0; index < data.output.length; index++){
          pre.innerHTML += data.output[index] + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("output").append(pre);
      }
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id='output'></div>
      <input type='TEXT' id='command' onchange='submitForm();'/>
    </body>
  </HTML>

/*** PYTHON ***/
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  import time;
  n = 0;
  while n < 5:
    print("THIS IS THE OUTPUT I NEED TO RETURN TO JSON");
    time.sleep(1);
```

Issue:
When I send the command as a single command, it returns the output; when I send the command to start a script, it returns null; how can I call the output as a JSON object to get the python script output that is run from the python script above.

Comment: or you could write to a log file?

Comment: I've tried to write to a log file; however, I come across two issues:
1. The customer will not change the python script to write to a log file (which would resolve the issue)
2. If I write to a file using python3 python.py >> output.log & the output will not write until the script is stopped
If you know a way of writing recursively without batch writing, I'm all ears.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get full input, output and error detail we need to use `proc_open` function in php. Php function reference can be consulted [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

```
<?php

    $data = (object) array();
    $data->command = $_POST['command'];

    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        2 => array("pipe", "r")   // stderr is a pipe to read from
    );

    $process = proc_open('python3 ' . $data->command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    //It is always a good idea to put full path e.g /usr/bin/python3
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0); //setting non-blocking on stderr
    fclose($pipes[0]); //closing input

    $data->output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); //reading output
    fclose($pipes[1]); //closing output

    $data->err = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]); //reading stderr
    fclose($pipes[2]); //closing stderr

    die(json_encode($data));
?>
```